# What is the origin of "slam-bang"?

Tags: etymology

What is the origin of *slam-bang*?

> I walked slam-bang into this character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I have my Green's open at nearly the right page (from a previous answer), I can suggest it could be one of two meanings; either "vigourously or energetically", or "precisely, directly". Both of these meanings date from ~1840. As to the origin, the earliest reference has a firearm sort of sound: "Down went the Major, shot right through the hips, *slam-bang*. (R.M.Bird, Nick of the Woods, 1837).

Answer (score 2):

Definitely onomatopoeic. I found [this reference](http://books.google.com/books?id=Z7kRAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA190&dq=%22slam%20bang%22&hl=en&ei=hiGsTdy4EJO10QHQ97z5CA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&sqi=2&ved=0CEkQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22slam%20bang%22&f=false) back to 1789, republished in the periodical [*The Polyanthos*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyanthos_%28magazine%29) in 1806:

[image: http://books.google.com/books?id=Z7kRAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA190&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&sig=ACfU3U0xxRynaWoIJSt2ldNQSM33n-6_uA&ci=125%2C1252%2C812%2C254&edge=0]

Interestingly, the phrase appeared again in the same magazine six years later in a [letter to the editor](http://books.google.com/books?id=DFEAAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA94&dq=%22slam%20bang%22&hl=en&ei=NTWsTayyGcjogQfltuHzBQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&sqi=2&ved=0CEQQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22slam%20bang%22&f=false) quoting some "famous Parson W____":

[image: http://books.google.com/books?id=DFEAAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA94&dq=%22slam%20bang%22&hl=en&ei=NTWsTayyGcjogQfltuHzBQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&sqi=2&ved=0CEQQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22slam%20bang%22&f=false]

And from six years later still, I found [this footnote](http://books.google.com/books?id=k7_kaJqXduMC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q=slam&f=false) to the use of the word *tamb* in the Doric pastoral, *The Exmoor Courtship*, exegeted in *Blackwood's Edinburgh Magazine*, 1819:

[image: http://books.google.com/books?id=kXAEAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA533&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&sig=ACfU3U300WKJndJyDQ1Zgh300CZhKKYZPA&ci=83%2C946%2C785%2C111&edge=0]

The "translator" dates the poem to the reign of Henry VII, but this all may have been a [ruse](http://spenserians.cath.vt.edu/TextRecord.php?&action=GET&textsid=34984).